# memcpy copied wrong data from tail of array

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a problem with memcpy function. I tried copy part of data from array of char but I was not success.

```
// Types
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;

// My variables
WORD bfType;
DWORD bfSize;
WORD bfReserved1;
WORD bfReserved2;
DWORD bfOffBits;

// My Func
void BmpFileHeader::setFileHeader(char* header)
{
    // header -> 42 4D BB E6 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00
    char* pointerOfHeader = header;
    std::memcpy(&bfType, header, sizeof(WORD));
    pointerOfHeader+=2;
    std::memcpy(&bfSize, pointerOfHeader, sizeof(DWORD));
    pointerOfHeader+=4;
    std::memcpy(&bfReserved1, pointerOfHeader, sizeof(WORD));
    pointerOfHeader+=2;
    std::memcpy(&bfReserved2, pointerOfHeader, sizeof(WORD));
    pointerOfHeader+=2;
    // This point, pointerOfHeader is 36(catched with debugging)
    std::memcpy(&bfOffBits, pointerOfHeader, sizeof(DWORD));
 }
```

All of my variables take true value except `bfOffBits` (example 7950260717192478774). I tried to change size but I was not succeed. What is the point I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean "pointerOfHeader is 36"? It should be `header + 10`

Comment: You'll want to be careful about endian issues when importing binary data.

Comment: How long is the `char* header` you're passing in?  Are you overshooting it? If your environment defines `unsigned long` as 64 bits you are.

Comment: You should be using `sizeof()` in you increment lines rather than hardcoded numbers

Comment: The 4 bytes you are trying to read into `bfOffBits` are `36 00 00 00`, which is decimal `54` (which is a correct offset for a BMP file). `bfOffBits` is declared as a `DWORD`, which shouldn't be able to hold a value of `7950260717192478774` (0x6E55000000000036) if it is a 32bit type. But, as a 64bit type, it can, but then 4 of the bytes will be undefined, as they will be read from memory that follows the header you are reading from.

Comment: Why not just `std::memcpy(&bfReserved1, pointerOfHeader, sizeof(bfReserved1));` so if you change the type for `bfReserved1` you don't have to fix it in the `memcopy` call?

Comment: You increment the pointer by the same `sizeof` in the `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though your compiler is treating `unsigned long` as a 64-bit quantity, but the Win32 API defines `DWORD` as an unsigned 32-bit value. Try:

```
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
```

Comment: or `unsigned int`, if the compiler treats `int` as a 4-byte type.

Comment: True, but that's still an *if*. Using `uint32_t` is either the correct size or doesn't compile at all - no possibility of getting it wrong.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and bfSize(unsigned long) variable take true value. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Yavuz: Your correct value for `bfSize` can be explained by: (a) the four trailing 00 bytes after the 32-bit `bfSize` value (which would get loaded into the upper 32 bits of a 64-bit value), and (b) your manual incrementing of the pointer by 4, when the compiler actually generated code to read 8 bytes.

Comment: @Yavuz we suggest you accept Greg's answer to fix this. `uint32_t` can be found in `#include <cstdint>` if you are using C++11 or newer.

Comment: I'd say it not only *appears*: BYTE, WORD and DWORD are by definition 8-, 16- and 32-bit types, respectively. Anything except `typedef uint8_t BYTE; typedef uint16_t WORD; typedef uint32_t DWORD;` is just wrong.

Comment: Yes, thank you @GregHewgill and of course thank you everyone in this post. I fix my code